# Iterator deletes first element which causes IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, iterator

Basically, there are response data which needs to be filtered. The response data consists of ListTrasporter which contains ListClass. It loops every ListTransporter and for each ListTransporter that has an empty ListClass - that ListTransporter element gets deleted. I used an iterator for doing that, here's the code:

```
Iterator<Transporter> iterator = item.getListTransporter().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Transporter trans = iterator.next();
    List<TransporterClass> responseType = trans.getListClass();
    if (responseType.isEmpty() || responseType.size() == 0) {
            iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when the first element contains data that gets filtered and deleted, it caused an IndexOutOfBoundsException error because of these lines of codes:

```
Transporter firstItemTransporter = firstItem.getListTransporter().get(0);
Transporter secondItemTransporter = secondItem.getListTransporter().get(0);
```

It calls first element, but the first element is empty. Is there a way to solve this error. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `firstItem.getListTransporter()` - check to see if empty first?

Comment: Why are you surprised that the loop might remove all items in the list, and hence leave the list empty, making `get(0)` fail?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your loop is removing all of the elements of your collection. You need to guard your code that tries to index into the collection with a check on the size of it like so:

```
if (!firstItem.getListTransporter().isEmpty()) {
     Transporter firstItemTransporter = firstItem.getListTransporter().get(0);
     ...
} else {
     // Handle there not being any data as you would expect.
}
```

You can check both `firstItem` and `secondItem` in the same check if it makes sense for your logic.